# anyway to control amount of data i want?

Tags: jsoup

i dont want to fetch "share" and "tweet" keyword when i crawl for list items on this page is there is anyway i can fix till which tag my crawl should bring me data

`<div id="main-content" tabindex="-1" role="main">
     <ul>
    <li>Comedones .</li></ul><ul>
    <li>Papules </li>
    <li>Pustules (pimples)</li>
    <li>Nodules</li>
    <li>Cysts</li></ul>
    <h3>When to see a doctor</h3><p>Acne diminished. </p>

    <div class="auto-mobile"></div>
    <menu class="social">
    <ul><li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer" class="facebook" >Share</a> </li>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status="class="twitter" >Tweet</a></li>
    </ul></menu>`

code i wrote to fetch li tags

```
Document doc2;
      doc2=Jsoup.connect("http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/acne/basics/symptoms/con-20020580").get();

      Elements ddd1=doc2.select("div#main-content ul li");


     for(Element a2: ddd1)
     {
        System.out.println( a2.text());

     }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "share" and "tweet". Do you mean you want to omit all ```<li>``` entries that contain links names "Share" and "Tweet"?

Comment: In the menu class =social  ul li a tags there is some more text " share " and "tweet" when i fetch all content of li tags they come along too they are problematic .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that the "Share" and "Tweet" `<li>` entries are embedded in a `<menu></menu>` construct. If all other `<ul><li></li></ul>` entries that you want are directly under the main `div#main-content`, then you can change the css selector to this:

```
Elements ddd1=doc2.select("div#main-content>ul li");
```

Explanation: `div#main-content>ul` contains the `>` which indicates that the `ul` entry must be a direct child of the `div#main-content`.

However, if there are other `<li>` entries deeper in the structure, you can filter out the links after you have applied your original selector:

```
for(Element a2: ddd1)
{
    if (a2.text().equals("Share") || a2.text().equals("Tweet")) continue;

    //now do your stuff
    System.out.println( a2.text());

}
```